# __init__ не принимает аргументы

Tags: python, аргументы

У меня разбит код на 3 файла. В 1 файле есть строка:

```
CommandsFilter('команда', prefixes = '+'
```

В 2 файле есть похожая строка:

```
CommandsFilter('команда', prefixes = '.')
```

3 файл -- **init** в котором просто импорт первых 2 файлов. При запуске мне выдает ошибку:

```
File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from command import (
  File "command\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .system import *
  File "command\system.py", line 23, in <module>
    CommandsFilter('команда', prefixes = '.')
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'prefixes'
```

Как сделать, чтобы **init** мог принять несколько аргументов?

Comment: Составьте [mcve]

Comment: Покажите текст самого метода `__init__`, подозреваю, что там `prefixes` идёт первым параметром (после `self`)

Comment: в __init__ только импорт модулей:
from .social import *
from .system import *